# How do I display the available disk space of a mount in specific format?

Tags: linux, display, disk-space, format

I would like to display the available disk space of a mount in `xx%` format,

For example:

```
sh-3.1$ df -h /opt/Application/Disk1/
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-LogVol09
                       57G   33G   22G  60% /opt/Application/Disk1/
```

I want to display only "%60"

Comment: It's already displaying like that. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams He only wants to display "60%" (or "%60", dunno). Not the entire output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

`df -h /opt/Application/Disk1/ | awk '{print $4}' | tail -1`

Here the `awk '{print $4}'` will print whatever appear in column 4 in your output and `tail -1` will filter out only the last line.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to display the available disk space of a mount in xx% format

...

> I want to display only "%60"

The example you gave doesn't quite fit the question since the *available* disk space in this example would be 40%. In case you wanted just to filter out the Output for the *used* disk space, you want to go with Eugene S's answer.
In case you wanted to express the *available* disk space in percent, you could use a modified version of it. Like this:

`df /opt/Application/Disk1/ | awk '{print (100 -$5 )}' | tail -1 | sed 's/^/%/g'`

Where `awk '{print (100 -$5 )}'`  subtracts the percentage of the *used* disk space (which is in the 5th column in normal output of `df`) from 100, which results in the percentage of the *available* disk space. The trailing `sed 's/^/%/g'` just adds the symbol % in front of the output. To add % after the output use `sed 's/$/%/g'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
st = os.statvfs(sys.argv[1])
free = st.f_bfree/st.f_blocks * 100
sys.stdout.write("%.f%%\n" % free)
```